# Perform CRUD for todos/tasks/appointments from Outlook?

Tags: c++, vba, outlook, com

How can I perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) for todos/tasks/appointments/etc from Outlook. Does Microsoft have a data api like Google that I can use to interact with Microsoft applications? I prefer this in C++ (Microsoft Visual C++), but Java will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial article which might be along the lines of what you are looking for: [Automate Microsoft Outlook from C++](http://www.olivierlanglois.net/Outlook_Automation_with_cpp.html)